# application:openURL:を使ってViewControllerを指定したい。

Tags: ios

application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:を用いてURLスキームより独自のアプリを起動しているのですが、TOPページより何回か遷移したDetailページをいきなり表示させることはできますでしょうか？また、そのページから戻る処理を行いTOPに戻ることもできればよいです。

Answer (score 1):

UINavigationControllerで管理しているビューコントローラでしたら、application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:メソッドで、Detailページのビューコントローラのインスタンスを確保し、-[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:]メソッドでDetailページを表示すすることで実装できると思います。

Comment: application:openURL:は AppDelegateに実装すればいいんですか？

Comment: 少し正確な書き方ではありませんでした。
起動される側のアプリのAppDelegateで次のメソッドを実装して、その中でDetailページを表示する処理を実装すれば良いと思います。

`- (BOOL)application(UIApplication *)application
openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
annotation:(id)annotation`